# Next.js Link tag not working in Hero.jsx and not redirecting to the expected URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx, next.js13

I'm facing an issue in my **Hero.jsx** component, which is implemented in **Page.js**. In Hero.jsx, I've added a button with a Link tag, and I want it to redirect to the **url.js** page. However, it's not working as expected and is showing an Error 404 page. I'm not sure if I'm implementing it incorrectly because I'm relatively new to Next.js. Could someone please help me resolve this issue?

Url Page:
[image: Link Page]

File Structure:
[image: File Structure]

Here's the code for reference:

In Hero.jsx:

```
import Link from "next/link"
const Hero = () => {
return (
    // ... other code ...
    <div className="items-center mx-auto justify-center text-center pt-16 z-20">
        <Link href="/url">
            <button className="bg-black text-white text-2xl px-10 py-5 rounded-lg shadow-xl shadow-black/40 hover:bg-gray-900 cursor-pointer">
                Get Started
            </button>
        </Link>
    </div>
    // ... other code ...
)}
export default Hero
```

In Page.js:

```
import Hero from "./components/Hero";
export default function Home() {
return (
    <section>
        <div className="h-10 w-full">
            <Hero />
            // ... other code ...
        </div>
    </section>
)}
```

In url.js:

```
export default function Lead() {
return (
    <div>
        <h1>Testing</h1>
    </div>
)}
```

I searched so much on different pages and the YouTube tutorials but didn't found the solution even chatGpt provides incorrect solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `url.js` to `url/page.jsx`

in the `app` folder. create a folder named `url` then create a file named `page.jsx` inside.

Comment: Now its working properly
I've a doubt that Is url/page.jsx file behave like url.js or it's a component which replaces the page and if I want other components can I use it on jsx or need to make another js file

Comment: `js` and `jsx` are the same it doesn't matter. 
what matters is the routing system is by folders not files. so if you want to create a new route create a folder and create a `page.js` file inside.